# How to use Codable protocol with reference types?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, codable

Example:

```
import Foundation

class Player: Codable {
   let name: String
   init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
   }
}

class Team: Codable {
   let players: [Player]
   let capitan: Player
   init(players: [Player], capitan: Player) {
      self.players = players
      self.capitan = capitan
   }
}

let player1 = Player(name: "p1")
let player2 = Player(name: "p2")

let team = Team(players: [player1, player2], capitan: player1)

print(team.players[0] === team.capitan) // true

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try encoder.encode(team)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let team2 = try decoder.decode(Team.self, from: data)

print(team2.players[0] === team2.capitan) // false
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

How to use Codable protocol with reference types?

The behavior may change in the future?
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0167-swift-encoders.md

Comment: I need reference types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fundamental to JSON, not Codable. JSON is an encoding of values. It does not keep track of references; it's not part of the format. If you want to keep track of references, you would have to store that in the JSON yourself, by encoding `objectIdentifier`. You'd then need to join up things that have the same identifier. But that's beyond the scope of Codable, since the underlying format doesn't have the concept. You'd need to create some other format (perhaps that used JSON as its underlying value format, in the way that `NSKeyedArchiver` uses property lists as its underlying value format).

JSON isn't an object graph storage format; as I said it's a value encoding. If you want an object graph, that's what `NSKeyedArchiver` is for. If you want a non-Cocoa solution, you would need to implement a new `Encoder` and `Decoder` that implemented the same basic idea as the archivers. That isn't what `JSONEncoder` is for. But I'd use `NSKeyedArchiver` if possible; it's designed for this.

Note that SE-0167 says that there is a new `encodeCodable` method on `NSKeyedArchiver` that is supposed to let you intermix `Codable` types with `NSCoding` types (and allow Swift types to participate in `NSKeyedArchiver`), but I don't see it in Xcode 9 beta 1.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0167-swift-encoders.md

In the future, NSKeyedArchiver will support method encodeCodable.
But I want to open text-based storage format (JSON).

Comment: "you would need to implement a new Encoder and Decoder that implemented the same basic idea as the archivers" - it is a variant

Comment: No such thing exists today in stdlib. You'd have to find it or build it.

Comment: @rtnm For now, you could add a persistent property `id: UUID` to your `Player` and store that `id` as your team's `captain`. Then implement your own `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` to translate this between the `id` and an actual `Player` reference (you'll search for your captain `Player` after first decoding all `players`). This is a nice workaround. Also, "Captain Playa" is a great band name. ;-)

Comment: You can likely `objectIdentifier` to achieve this (rather than creating your own `id`), but implementing it will require some kind of custom `Encoder`/`Decoder` or a post-processing step to de-duplicate.

Comment: @RobNapier, same result
`let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver()
try! archiver.encodeEncodable(team, forKey: "team")
archiver.finishEncoding()
let data = archiver.encodedData

let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
let team2 = unarchiver.decodeDecodable(Team.self, forKey: "team")!

print(team2.players[0] === team2.capitan) // false`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the encoder currently does not respect references and instead saves a separate instance of the same object each time it is referenced, which is why `===` fails. You can change it to `==` and implement `Equatable` for your classes which should fix this, or as the comment on the question states, use structs.

Comment: I want to get an exact copy after decoding.